# How does inference work on a Transformer?

Tags: machine-learning, transformers, machine-translation

(Let's say I trained a transformer for translation.)

In the training, the output sentences are given and fed into the decoder as a whole. However, with inference, only a start-of-sentence (SOS) token is given. How does the model know what word to choose to start the sentence? And how does it know what subsequent words to choose?

I know that the decoder has a feedforward network after its attention heads. Is the choosing done in this part of the decoder (I know the output is a list of probabilities, but I am ignoring those for simplicity)?

Comment: because the "whole sequence" is done just for efficiency at training time, and it's masked so that it behaves as during inference...

Comment: in other words, it knows what it's after SOS because it's been trained to learn it, and you have the context given from the encoder to have a good clue what to predict

Answer (score 3):

The decoder computes the probability of the next word given the words that have already been decoded. Given words $1, \ldots, n$, the model computes a categorical distribution over the output vocabulary and decides the next word. This word is then prepended to the input, so we have words $1, \ldots, n+1$, which can be used to predict the $(n + 2)$-nd word. This is repeated until the `[EOS]` token is generated. There are various strategies for how the next token is decided: the most common strategies are greedily taking the most probable word or using beam search.

At training time, this autoregressive self-feeding is simulated by providing the ground truth sentence as an input with prepended `[SOS]` symbol and the same sentence as the output with appended `[EOS]` symbols. Therefore, we know the decoder's entire input and output at training time. This way of training is called teacher forcing. This cause that for $(n-1)$-th input word, the probability of the $n$-th word is predicted. Additionally, at training time, there is a mask to prevent self-attention only to consider the left context.

Comment: adding to this: the first token predicted after seeing [SOS] is also a function of the encoding of the sentence to be translated. It is not generated contextless.